# Problem with the line of reasoning used by Feynman in a proof that the force felt by a point outside the earth can be approximated by a point mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, symmetry

I was following the proof in the lecture 13 of Feynman Volume 1 where he proves that the force produced by the earth on a point outside or on the surface of it is equal to force produced by a point mass located at the center of the earth with a mass equal to that of the earth. I am having trouble validating the beginning of this proof.

He starts by considering a differential mass $dm = 2 \pi y µds$. My confusion lies in why using $ds$ is valid. Intuitively since the area of a cylinder is $2 \pi r h$ it feels like if you cut off the small triangle at the top of the circle you would get a cylinder with area $2 \pi y dx% $ and thus $dm = 2 \pi y µ dx$. Though this approximation seems to fail at the end of the circle where slope is almost vertical. Still, I would like to see a more rigorous justification and intuition for why Feynman's line of reasoning works.

[image]

Comment: So you are asking if calculus works or not? In the limit $ds$ goes to zero the error goes to zero even faster.

Comment: Yes, this proof is as rigorous as is the foundations of differential/integral calculus. Even in the precalculus age the Greeks (Archimedes) reasoned that a circular arc could be approximated by many small polygonal segments. I

Comment: It's a fine illustration of how mathematical proofs can mislead in reality. The regression of the line of nodes is a large effect for low Earth orbiting spacecraft, but the gravity of a point mass shouldn't cause such a thing.

Comment: Link to Feynman lecture page?

Comment: @JohnDoty Good point! The Earth is not a uniformly spherical, uniform mass distribution. Kinda neat how mathematical idealizations have gotten humanity as far as it has! btw, you must be a Nasa guy?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus I'm an astrophysicist. I work with NASA, JAXA, various universities, ...

Comment: The original poster simply asks about the reasoning used in one of Feynmann's lectures on physics, they did not even ask how to perform the calculation or get the answer. No way this should have been closed because it was a check my work or homework problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to approach this problem using the machinery of integral calculus in such a way as to avoid the whole differential triangle issue. For example, if one assumes that the divergence theorem is rigorous, then one can utilize Gauss' law to obtain the following:
$$\oint -\nabla\Phi\cdot d\vec a=-4\pi GM.$$ Where the gravitational force on the point mass is $\vec F=-m\nabla\Phi$ and $M$ is the total mass of the spherical distribution in question (Earth) such that $M=\int \rho dV$. Since the problem exhibits spherical symmetry, the gravitational field $\nabla\Phi$ is radial and one gets:
$$-4\pi|\nabla\Phi|r^2=-4\pi GM,$$ which leads to:$$\vec F={GMm\over r^2}\vec e_r.$$ Exactly the expression for the gravitational force exerted by a point mass.